# Как вывести строки, у которых одно и то же значение в полях "название" и "признак", но разные значения в поле "номер"?

Tags: sql, group-by, оконные-функции

Допустим, есть таблица (см. ниже). Как вывести строки, у которых одно и то же значение в полях <kbd>название</kbd> и <kbd>признак</kbd>, но разные значения в поле <kbd>номер</kbd>?

То есть нужно вывести строки:

- `5 - name  - black`.
- `1 - name  - black`.
- `6 - name4 - red`.
- `4 - name4 - red`.

| номер | название | признак |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | black |
| 1 | name | black |
| 5 | name | black |
| 1 | name | black |
| 2 | name2 | blue |
| 3 | name3 | grey |
| 4 | name4 | red |
| 6 | name4 | red |
| 4 | name4 | red |

Comment: @Kromster https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2412/532877

Comment: @Зонтик надеюсь вы и сами будете следовать совету из ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2412/532877 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбрать строки, у которых название и признак одинаковый, но разные значения в поле номер можно с использованием оконных фукнций:

```
select distinct c."название", c."признак", c."номер" from (
  select 
    "название", 
    "признак", 
    "номер",
    count(*) over (partition by "название", "признак") cnt
  from test
) c
where c.cnt > 1
order by "название", "признак"
```

Результат:

| название | признак | номер |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name | black | 1 |
| name | black | 5 |
| name4 | red | 6 |
| name4 | red | 4 |

[Песочница db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rPF4T5XgtQJRzkRwdBofuy/0)

Comment: Можно еще кое-что добавить. Что если столбцы взяты из разных таблиц?

Comment: @Екатерина Смотря как эти столбцы взяты. Если простой join, то разницы нет, если это результат каких то группировок, то, возможно, это надо будет обернуть в отдельный подзапрос. Я отталкивался из вашего примера, что эти значения лежат в одной таблице

Comment: @Екатерина Попробуйте с этим примером, должно получиться. Если нет, оформите новый вопрос, указав все детали. Какие таблицы есть, как вы их сцепляете, какой результат получаете, что далее хотите получить и что не получается.

Comment: select distinct c."название", c."признак", c."номер" from (      -- после distinct непонятно как наименования полей задать
  select таблица1."название", таблица2."признак", таблица1."номер"
    from таблица1 join таблица2 on таблица1.допустимid = таблица2.полесэтимid
) c
where c.cnt > 1
order by "название", "признак"

Comment: @Екатерина Результатом вложенного запроса будет таблица с алиасом **c**, так что можно не менять ничего. Если у вас возникают ошибка, оформите новый вопрос, указав, в каких таблицах что лежит, как вы их соединяете и так далее... Сложно угадывать, что там у вас на самом деле.

Comment: Создала задачу для в случае joinов , все же меня смущает distinct в начале.Получается выводятся все уникальные записи по трем полям, а в условии немного другое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1547289/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86-%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0

Comment: получилось, спасибо, добрый воин

Answer (score -1):

Что-то подобное что ли?

```
# Создаем список строк таблицы
table = [
    [1, 'name', 'black'],
    [1, 'name', 'black'],
    [5, 'name', 'black'],
    [1, 'name', 'black'],
    [2, 'name2', 'blue'],
    [3, 'name3', 'grey'],
    [4, 'name4', 'red'],
    [6, 'name4', 'red'],
    [4, 'name4', 'red']
]

# Создаем пустой список для хранения результатов
result = []

# Создаем множество для отслеживания уникальных комбинаций "название" и "признак"
seen = set()

# Проходим по каждой строке таблицы
for row in table:
    # Получаем значения полей "номер", "название" и "признак"
    number, name, attribute = row
    
    # Создаем уникальный идентификатор для комбинации "название" и "признак"
    identifier = (name, attribute)
    
    # Проверяем, есть ли уже такая комбинация в множестве seen
    if identifier in seen:
        # Если комбинация уже встречалась, добавляем строку в результат
        result.append(row)
    else:
        # Если комбинация встречается впервые, добавляем ее в множество seen
        seen.add(identifier)

# Выводим результат
for row in result:
    print(row)
```

Comment: И где здесь sql?

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайте внимание на метки вопроса. Вы привели код на [tag:python], но вопрос был о [tag:sql]. То есть этот ответ не поможет ни автору сообщения, ни другим людям, поэтому возможно, вам стоит его удалить.