# Как вывести строки из разных таблиц, у которых одно и то же значение в полях "название" и "признак", но разные значения в поле "номер"?

Tags: sql

Допустим, есть 2 таблицы (см. ниже). Как вывести строки, у которых одно и то же значение в полях "название" и "признак", но разные значения в поле "номер"? таблицы связать через "from Цветономера join Названия on Цветономера.id = Названия.цветономер"
То есть нужно вывести строки, у которых совпадают "название" и "признак", при этом если номера у них одинаковые, то выводить их не нужно. Но если есть строки с неуникальными номерами и получается одинаковыми полями "название" и "признак" , то вывести эту уникальную строку с отличным номером и сгруппированную строку, где все поля одинаковые:
|122|black|1|
|123|black|5|
|128|red|4|
|129|red|7|

таблица "Цветономера"

| id | признак | номер |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | black | 1 |
| 122 | black | 1 |
| 123 | black | 5 |
| 124 | black | 1 |
| 125 | blue | 8 |
| 126 | blue | 8 |
| 127 | red | 4 |
| 128 | red | 4 |
| 129 | red | 7 |

таблица "Названия"

| название | цветономер |
| --- | --- |
| name | 121 |
| name | 122 |
| name | 123 |
| name | 124 |
| name | 125 |
| name | 126 |
| name4 | 127 |
| name4 | 128 |
| name4 | 129 |

Запрос ниже, который был ранее в комментариях к вопросу со значениями из одной таблицы , возможно, корректный. Только как быть со значениями из разных таблиц?

```
select distinct c."название", c."признак", c."номер" from (
  select 
    "название", 
    "признак", 
    "номер",
    count(*) over (partition by "название", "признак") cnt
  from test
) c
where c.cnt > 1
order by "название", "признак"
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем ответ такой:

```
select distinct c.название , c.признак, c.номер from (
  select НЗ.название , ЦН.признак, ЦН.номер,
  count(*) over (partition by НЗ.название , ЦН.признак, ЦН.номер) cnt
  from  Цветономера as ЦН
  join Названия as НЗ on ЦН.ID = НЗ.цветономера ) c
where c.cnt > 1
order by c.название , c.признак
```